# length of textbox contents returning only 1 when it should be more

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox that I check in jquery to see if the length is less than 11 chars long.  In testing, I 've entered ten chars but the length method returns only one.

This is my text box:

```
<input type="text" id="txtMyText" name="myText" value="testing" onblur = "chkInput()"/>
```

My function chkInput is called when I exit this box but wasn't working as I expected.  So I inserted an alert with the length attribute:

```
alert("Text " + $("#txtMyText").length);
```

The alert shows that the length = 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the length *of the text* of the [`textarea` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html):

```
alert('Text ' + $('#txtMyText').val().length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
alert("Text " + $("#txtMyText").val().length);
```

This will give you the length *of the value* stored in the textbox.  Your code is telling you the number of elements selected by jQuery, which is one.

Answer (score 0):

Your Jquery selector is returning an array with one member - not a string you can use .length on. Get the length of the *val* property of the DOM node instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's because, you are doing it all wrong. You were very near though. First , you have to get the `value`, then you must try to get `length` of the value.

**HTML"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="txtMyText" name="myText" value="testing12345" onblur = "chkInput()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
alert("Text :::" + $("#txtMyText").val().length);
```

See the working example here : http://jsbin.com/AtOJiyi/1/edit

Remember  to `run with js`.